# I want to make accordion in ng-repeat loop using angularjs only with no ui.bootstrap and no jquery

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

I tried using the code given below. This code is not collapsing others. It simply leave other panels open.I want to close other panels on clicking of the current panel. Any help will be appreciated without using jQuery and ui.bootstrap

```html
<div id="accordion" class="panel-group">
    <div ng-repeat="item in awesomeThings" >
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                 <h4 class="panel-title">
                     <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
                        href="#collapse{{$index+1}}"
                        ng-click="print($event)" class="nothing" >click</a>
                 </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse{{$index+1}}" class="panel-collapse collapse ">
                <div class="panel-body">
               {{item.item}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the controller part in which I tried adding the collapsed class to all and then adding the `in` class to the current clicked item and also removing the collapsed class from the current item

```
$scope.print= function($event){
   var el= angular.element(document.querySelector('.nothing'));
   console.log(el);
   el.addClass('collapsed');
   angular.element($event.target).removeClass('collapsed');
   angular.element($event.target).addClass('in');
}
```

Comment: Assumed that `in` class shows the item and `collapsed` hides it, you code is find. If you can create a [runnable code](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) (or https://codesandbox.io/, https://jsbin.com/ etc.) we could try to debug it.

Comment: Here is runnable code. https://jsbin.com/noxilacuve/edit?html,output

Comment: I was wrong, there is an issue with your code :\ See my answer.

Comment: is the answer working for you? Is there any problem?

Comment: Yes , I removed both the lines having angular.element and it is still working fine.

Comment: You're right. I updated my answer. Please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it so it will help to other people.

Comment: Can i ask you another question ??

Comment: Sure. But please create another question so it will be more organized. You can post the link here.

Comment: Now, I tried the same in bootstrap tables but table is not rendering properly. Here is link https://jsbin.com/zemuyakavo/edit?html,output

Comment: I meant please hit the `Ask question` button and create a whole new question to not spam this one. Once you created the question, you can paste here the link **to the question** (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/....)

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience.. Now i have posted the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60740757/i-am-making-accordion-on-bootstrap-tables-with-data-coming-from-ng-repeat-loop-w

Comment: No problem. Seems like someone already answered you. Is it working for you?

Comment: No , I want that collapsible div right below the current clicked row. Please help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `document.querySelector` returns only the first match but you want to get them all. `querySelectorAll` won't do the job either because you target the `<a />` tags which change their `class`es will do nothing.

If any, you can change the `class`es of the `.collapse` elements - remove `in` and add `collapsed`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('ngapp', []);
    app.controller('mainctrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.awesomeThings = [{
        item: 'heoj'
      }, {
        item: 'nniothing'
      }, {
        item: 'skgjs'
      }];
      $scope.print = function($event) {
        var el = angular.element('.panel-collapse');
        el.removeClass('in').addClass('collapsed');
        angular.element($event.target).removeClass('collapsed');
        angular.element($event.target).addClass('in');
      }
    })
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="ngapp" ng-controller="mainctrl">
  <div id="accordion" class="panel-group">
    <div ng-repeat="item in awesomeThings">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse{{$index+1}}" ng-click="print($event)" class="nothing">click</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse{{$index+1}}" class="panel-collapse collapse ">
          <div class="panel-body">
            {{item.item}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

https://jsbin.com/momuniz/edit?html,output

---

But this will hide the expanded panels without animation because changing the classes is not enough, it should be with timing so the collapse will be smooth.

To fix it, we need bootstrap to do the collapse and there is an API for that: [`collapse ()`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#via-javascript).

So instead of remove and add `class`es by yourself, let bootstrap to do it with

```js
el.collapse('hide')
```

**Live example**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('ngapp', []);
    app.controller('mainctrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.awesomeThings = [{
        item: 'heoj'
      }, {
        item: 'nniothing'
      }, {
        item: 'skgjs'
      }];
      $scope.print = function($event) {
        angular.element('.panel-collapse').collapse('hide');
      }
    })
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="ngapp" ng-controller="mainctrl">
  <div id="accordion" class="panel-group">
    <div ng-repeat="item in awesomeThings">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse{{$index+1}}" ng-click="print($event)" class="nothing">click</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse{{$index+1}}" class="panel-collapse collapse ">
          <div class="panel-body">
            {{item.item}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

https://jsbin.com/nigumad/edit?html,output

By the way, you don't need `querySelector/All` when you use `angular.element` because you can pass the selector directly to `angular.element` - `angular.element('.nothing')`